# inkscape - how to remove contour when exporting to png?

Tags: inkscape, pixel

the inkscape I configured it in this way

[image]

now I select the figure that I want to export

[image]

I use the filter to pixelate

[image]

and to export use this option

[image]

But there is a transparent outline ("in the image below is dark gray") that remains and my goal is that the figure occupies all the space

[image]
[Shared file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/way82do5ax1pya1/example.svg/file)

Comment: Can you share the SVG file? If not, check if there is a filter applied to the object, or if you have the wrong object selected during export.

Comment: sorry, I just upload now you can download it and verify that it is wrong. I use version 92.3

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be the following:

- create a rectangle of the dimension of the graph (64x64)
- place in the middle of the graph. (rectangle selected)
- Make the **rectangle transparent** (selected rectangle)

and finally, **select the rectangle** and export

Answer (score 0):

The object has a filter applied to it (the pixelize filter). Filters have a 'filter region' that usually is a bit larger than the object they are applied to. This makes the objects look larger

Either:

- remove the filter (Filters > Remove filters) and draw the image yourself
- change the size of the filter area (Filters > Filter editor with object selected)
- change the page size to the green square (without filter) and export the page area after  reapplying the filter
- opt to use the geometrical instead of the visual bounding box (Edit > Preferences > Tools: Geometrical bounding box) - this is probably the easiest method in your case. Remember to change the option back when exported objects are too small (i.e. their strokes or shadows are missing).